# Rename folder that contains opened files in a Windows server shared resource

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ntfs, windows-cluster, rename

This is a Windows 2012 Cluster with a File server role.

I'm trying to rename a folder that contains several files and other folders that are in use by users and the OS says that:

[image]

Is it possible to rename a folder whereas some users are working on this folder?

I assume that all the opened files within that folder have to be closed to be able to rename the folder, but maybe there's a more productive way to solve that issue.

Thank you.

Comment: **Is it possible to rename a folder whereas some users are working on this folder?** - No it isn't. You'll have to wait for the files to be closed by the users or you'll have to forcefully close the files.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You need to either wait for a time when nobody is accessing that folder, ot to forcefully close all connections to it or its contents (this can be done via Computer Management -> Shared Folders -> Open Files).